# Using AlertManager to alert on Ping Failure of Remote Pods

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

In Prometheus using AlertManager I am trying to write an alert for a custom metric that stores a timestamp for the last ping of a node in a cluster.  If you look at it in the graph with without filters, it scales linearly upwards.

I have tried using other functions, like rate(), changes(), resets(), with limited results.

I have come up with something that looks like below with limited results:
`delta(ping_timestamp[5m]) < 20`

My goal is to find 5 minute gaps in response before I alert  on it.  Although I was wondering if there might be a better solution.

Comment: You basically want 'up' metric which prometheus provides. You don't need to store timestamp for the last ping. All you need is a 1/0 values (did respond, didn't respond) and then you can set alert like:  expr: custom_metric == 0
    for: 5m